# Get all values from dynamically generated (and dragged) elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamically generated and sorted elements "session" with textarea within each one. I want to get all text values from these elements with "paragraph" as data-type.

Generated element :

```
<session>
     <textarea data-type="paragraph">text_1</textarea>
</session>

<session>
     <textarea data-type="paragraph">text_2</textarea>
</session>

<session>
     <textarea data-type="paragraph">text_3</textarea>
</session>
```

EDIT: This doesn't work

```
$(function () {
     var $elements = $('[data-type]')
    , values = $elements.map(function () {
    return $(this).innerText;
    }).get();
    console.log(values);    
});
```

This gives an array of the section types

```
let sections = $("section").map((e, i) => $(e).data("type"))
```

I want text_1, text_2 and text_3 (all editable) and dynamically generated)

Comment: I think you can simply replace `data("type")` with `innerText` ;

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work (I edited my question)

Comment: Textareas are form input fields, so you would actually use **.val()** in jquery

Comment: Elaborate on "it doesn't work." Does anything happen? is there an error in the console? What have you done to debug?

Comment: it shows this : []

Answer (score 0):

Trying with val() instead of innerText is working :

```
$(function () {
    var $elements = $('[data-type]')
   , values = $elements.map(function () {
   return $(this).val();
   }).get();
   console.log(values);    
});
```